# 3x3 2d matrix multiplication in C

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, formula, multiplication

[enter image description here][1]

What is the best way to compute this equation? This is my attempt, I sort of get the right answers for out[2] and out[3] but I'm sure there is a better way of doing this. I attempted structs but didn't have any luck. Are the data types correct for negative numbers? and will they be carried through to the output when adding and multiplying?

Thanks for any advice!

```
int main() {
int i, j;
int array[i][j];

array[1][1]= 257; array[1][2]= 504; array[1][3]= 98;
array[2][1]= -148; array[2][2]= -291; array[2][3]= 439;
array[3][1]= 439; array[3][2]= 368; array[3][3]= 71;



int input[3];

float R=0.2, G=2, B=5;

input[2]=R;
input[2]=G;
input[3]=B;


float tot[3];

tot[2]=input[2]*array[1][1] + input[2]*array[1][2] + input[3]*array[1][3];
tot[2]=input[2]*array[2][1] + input[2]*array[2][2] + input[3]*array[2][3];
tot[3]=input[2]*array[3][1] + input[2]*array[3][2] + input[3]*array[3][3];



int add[3];

add[2]=16;
add[2]=128;
add[3]=128;


float out[3];

out[2]=add[2]+tot[2];
out[2]=add[2]+tot[2];
out[3]=add[3]+tot[3];

int z;
for (z = 0; z < 3; z++)
 {
      printf("\nout[z] = %f", out[z]);
 }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to compute this equation?

Depends on the equation you want to solve. Maybe you wanted to post the equation in the link you tried to provide. If you correct the link, somebody may be able to tell you.

> Are the data types correct for negative numbers?

In short: you can use int. But: Maybe you read more about data types in c and the differences between integer and unsigned integer. You also declare "input[]" as int but assign floats.

> I sort of get the right answers for out[2] and out[3]

You access all your arrays with two times [2].

```
input[2]=R;
input[2]=G;
input[3]=B;
```

Assuming your array access starts with 1, you should do

```
input[1]=R;
input[2]=G;
input[3]=B;
```

By the way my results were after correcting the index values of the arrays:

```
1565.4
1445.0
3937.0
```